# Action Bar Sherlock black bar when holding on a Menu Item

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm using a normal Action Bar Sherlock `Action Bar` but noticed that, if I opted to hold down on the item as opposed to clicking on it, a black box would appear. I have two questions:
What is its intended purpose?
How do I get rid of it?

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button_actionbar"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh_circle"
        android:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

</menu>
```

onOptionsItemSelected:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.refresh_button_actionbar:
        this.refresh();
        break;
    default: 
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black box is somekind of toast indicating the "description" of your button.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/refresh_button_actionbar"
    android:icon="@drawable/refresh_circle"
    android:title="Refresh" 
    android:showAsAction="always">
```

Add the `android:title` tag into your menu item and you will see it appear on black box, not sure how to get rid of it tough.

Comment: Ah, that's what I thought it was used for. Just as long as it doesn't look like a bug is good enough for me :P
Thank you!!